# Function fails to finish

Tags: python

I am writing a script to log into a switch, write the config to a file, and then rename the file. I have the parts working separately. The issue is that I cannot figure out how to get all parts with in the same function so that I can use the function on a list of devices. I get a file not open for reading in the for 'line in f' statement. when as far as i can see the file is still open. 
I have tried writing a function to rename the file that works on its own, but not when in this script with the other parts. 
I have another script that i wrote that has the rename portion outside of the function which works, but will not work to rename the file if multiple hosts are called with the Exscript 'quickstart' module. 
Thanks for any help,

```
from Exscript.util.start import quickstart
import os
import datetime
import time


time = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%d-%m-%Y")
tm = 'c:/test/tmp.txt'


def do_something(job, host, conn):

    f = open(tm, 'w+') #opens File with read and write permissions  
    conn.execute('term len 0')
    conn.execute('sh run')
    f.write(conn.response)
    conn.execute('quit')

#this is the part where the error comes
    for line in f:
        if "hostname" in line:
        host = line.strip()




    test = 'c:/test/' + host[9:] + 'on' + time + '.txt'
    os.rename(tm, test) 

quickstart('ssh://x.x.x.x', do_something)
```

Comment: `#this is the part where the error comes` - it'd help if you posted the full traceback...

Comment: As an aside - I'm not sure what this `Exscript` is - but it kind of looks like you could make use of [fabric](http://docs.fabfile.org/en/1.8/)

Answer (score 0):

According to the [manual](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#open), mode `w+` truncates (removes all the content from) the file.  If you want to open the file for both reading and writing without destroying its contents, use mode `r+` or `a+`.

::edit:: Note, I'm not sure how this works on Windows.

Comment: Thanks to all for the help, In full discloseure i have to admit a newbie mistake of editing code on one directory and running it on the command line from another directory. Once I ran the correct code from the correct directory all worked as expected. 

Sorry for wasting your time.

Answer (score 0):

You have to test the file pointer at the beginning of the file using `f.seek(0)`. Or first write to the file then close it then reopen it for reading. But you dont need a file at all - you can as well work on a local variable.